# User Classification in RapidMiner - output should be the user based on a fed test data

Tags: classification, rapidminer

How can I use RapidMiner to run the classifier on a test data, and classify a user based on that data - I need it to actually output who the classified user is, and not its performance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question!

You just have to use an example (row) with Attributes(Column Headers) and then feed it to the *Apply Model* operator. Make sure you remove the label(or what you want to be predicted) from that example.

The results will give you a row with an added attribute called *Prediction*.